# Expire an odoo sesstion after certain idle time on browser (since last activity)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo9, I want to log off user if it has spent 5 mins idle time on browser (since last activity)? Any Idea how to do this in odoo 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the better module to manage the inactive session for Odoo-9. Its a free OCA module.
Please try this one.

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/auth_session_timeout/

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult since Odoo makes ajax request from time to time to do some stuffs like calendar and bus notifications. So first of all you will need to disable the bus js longpolling and after that you could get the logout stuff by using a Session Store like Redis where keys containing Session Information could be destroyed after some time of no update usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ready-made OCA module auth_session_timeout  for this. You can find it at https://github.com/OCA/server-auth/tree/11.0/auth_session_timeout.